# pushing arguments to a JavaScript function vs pulling the values from the page

Tags: javascript, php, function

Total newbie here so please be kind.  I have a javascript function.  I have an element in a php page that calls the function.  In the page I have elements with variables populated from queries.

I can get the variable data I need for my function by either pushing them as arguments.

```
  function myFunc(arg1,arg2,arg3)
```

Or pulling them from my page from within the function

```
    var arg1 = document.getElementById(arg1_id).innerHTML
    var arg2 = document.getElementById(arg2_id).innerHTML
    var arg3 = document.getElementById(arg3_id).innerHTML
//do something with the data
```

So my question is, which is the best/most common method to use?

As I say I am new but loving it so i want to try and learn and use best practice.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: In my understanding, second approach would suit your requirement as you have elements and `innerHTML` can change anytime. So if you fetch from innerHTML, you will have a stable source. Also this would allow you to move event binding to JS

Comment: it depends, if you wanna use the arguments later in the code or maybe inside other functions, you can define the m in the page, but if you only wanna use them inside `myFunc` then you better pass them as arguments, also this way it'd be more structured and easier to understand and that's why most of the times I personally pass arguments even if I have to use them later in the code!

Comment: @Rajesh that's correct, but still you have to push the variables as arguments when using the function, right?

Comment: @AminJafari I don't think I follow. If you are passing `id`s as arguments, just hardcode them in your JS function. Yes hardcoding is bad,  but there is some level that you cannot avoid. If you wish to pass them as args, you will have to hardcode them on server side. So you will have to hardcode them. I'd prefer that on JS as JS is responsible with UI/DOM manipulation and server should not know about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented,

> In my understanding, second approach would suit your requirement as you have elements and innerHTML can change anytime. So if you fetch from innerHTML, you will have a stable source. Also this would allow you to move event binding to JS

I would suggest you to use second approach (`fetching from elements`).

**Reason**

- If you change `innerHTML`, then your args will point to incorrect data. Fetching from elements will prevent this.
- If you have changing/ long list of variables, it will become ugly to pass them as arguments.
- If you have binding handler form HTML, you cannot have dynamic values. Them become static once page is rendered.

```js
function notify(str){
  console.log(str)
}

document.getElementById('userNotify').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var user = document.getElementById('txtUser').value;
  notify('Hello ' + user)
})
```

```html
<div onclick="notify('Hello')">Click me</div>
<input id="txtUser" />
<div id="userNotify">Click me</div>
```

- Binding from HTML does not binds `this` context with current element. So you will have to pass `id` as parameter and again fetch it in code. `addEventListener` binds it by default.

```js
function notify(el) {
  console.log(this, el);
}

document.getElementById('second').addEventListener('click',notify)
```

```html
<div onclick="notify(this)">Click me</div>
<div id="second">Click me</div>
```

- If you bind in HTML and do `element.onchange = function(){ ... }`, your previous binding is lost. Using `addEventListener` would solve this.

```js
function notify(str){
  console.log(str)
}

document.getElementById('clickme').onclick = function(){
  console.log('Opps! Listener Changed')
}
```

```html
<div id="clickme" onclick="notify('Hello')">Click me</div>
```

- Another issue with passing values as parameter in HTML handler is that it is hack-able. [Sample JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/7swejem6/1/).

**Note:** above reasons are eligible if you have editable values which are mapped to a DOM elements and would be visible to User.

If not, if these are static values that should remain same through out page's life-cycle and are only for internal processing, passing them as parameters make more sense. Creating a hidden field for them is a bad option. You should rather have a API call or have a function in JS on `.html` page that can access these variables and save them some where other than Global scope. This will prevent `hack` mentioned above.

Comment: Rajesh: Thank you for your prompt response. Your second point prompted my question. To your first; I would use hidden <div>s to hold the variables in a controlled way. The values would depend on the criteria driving the queries that yield them. Sorry I don't understand your third. same for point four and five.  I better go do some research.

Comment: @Bri, the values that your code would depend, are they editable on any element? If yes, this would suit you. If you have static values that would not be displayed and you are planning to have hidden elements to hold them, then passing them as parameter make more sense.

Comment: @Bri I have tried to add snippets to explain points. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort you have spent it answering my question, it is greatly appreciated.  Your snippets and explanations are excellent although possible beyond me today, tomorrow may be different. :).

Comment: My php code draws its data from a db using PDO and builds a responsive page depending on the db table.   When the user updates the data it sends the data from the field on Change to the function along with the table name, field name record primary Key; old data, new data logged in user name.  The function will update the db using AJAX and feed back to the page by displaying a tick to confirm the data has been saved.